# Mongoose structure aggregation output without field names

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using aggregate to paginate data from subdocuments. The subdocuments don't have a strict schema so they can be different for each document, this is making it difficult for me to structure my output as I don't know the field names for the subdocuments.

### What I am using

Mongo 3.0.0

Node 0.10.33

Mongoose 3.9.7

### My models

```
var BodySchema = new Schema({random: String},{strict:false});

var FeedSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    body:[BodySchema]
});
```

### My data looks like this

```
[{
    _id:"...",
    name:"Power Rangers feed",
    body:[
        {
            "_id":"...",
            "name" : "Jason",
            "colour" : "Red",
            "animal" : "T-rex"
        },
        {
            "_id":"...",
            "name" : "Billy",
            "colour" : "Blue",
            "animal" : "Triceratops"
        },
        {
            "_id":"...",
            "name" : "Zach",
            "colour" : "Black",
            "animal" : "Mastadon"
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id:"...",
    name:"Transformers feed",
    body:[
        {
            "_id":"...",
            "name" : "Optimus Prime",
            "team" : "Autobots",
            "class" : "leader"
            "alt-mode" : "truck"
        },
        {
            "_id":"...",
            "name" : "Bumblebee",
            "team" : "Autobots",
            "class" : "scout"
            "alt-mode" : "VW Beetle"
        },
        {
            "_id":"...",
            "name" : "Blaster",
            "team" : "Autobots",
            "class" : "Commmunicator"
            "alt-mode" : "Sterio"
        },
        {
            "_id":"...",
            "name" : "Hotrod",
            "team" : "Autobots",
            "class" : "Warrior"
            "alt-mode" : "Car"
        }
    ]
}]
```

### My current aggregate code looks like this

```
feed.aggregate([
    {'$match':{_id:id('550234d3d06039d507d238d8')}},
    {'$unwind':'$body'},
    {'$skip':2},
    {'$limit':2},
    {
        '$project': {
            '_id':"$body._id",
            'body': "$body"
        }

    },
], function(err, result){

    if(err){return(res.send(500, err))}

    res.send(result);

});
```

### My current result looks like this

```
[{
    _id:"...",
    body:{
        "_id":"...",
        "name" : "Blaster",
        "team" : "Autobots",
        "class" : "Commmunicator"
        "alt-mode" : "Sterio"
    }
},
{
    _id:"...",
    body:{
        "_id":"...",
        "name" : "Hotrod",
        "team" : "Autobots",
        "class" : "Warrior"
        "alt-mode" : "Car"
    }
}]
```

### My desired result looks like this

```
[
    {
        "_id":"...",
        "name" : "Blaster",
        "team" : "Autobots",
        "class" : "Commmunicator"
        "alt-mode" : "Sterio"
    },
    {
        "_id":"...",
        "name" : "Hotrod",
        "team" : "Autobots",
        "class" : "Warrior"
        "alt-mode" : "Car"
    }
]
```

### My Question

How can I achieve my desired result structure.

Comment: Nicely structured question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you are going to hate this, but this is just how the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages in the aggregation pipeline work. You need to specify all of the fields that you want in the output "explicitly". Therefore:

```js
feed.aggregate([
    {'$match':{_id:id('550234d3d06039d507d238d8')}},
    {'$unwind':'$body'},
    {'$skip':2},
    {'$limit':2},
    {
        '$project': {
            '_id':"$body._id",
            'name': '$body.name',
            'team': '$body.team',
            'class': '$body.alt-mode'
        }
    },
], function(err, result){
```

That really is the only way to do it.

There really is a strong reasoning behind that though, and most of the principles are backed up in SQL SELECT, with the exception of the `*` "wildcard" where applicable.

The general premise is that this is analogous to unix `pipe` in general operation so if you think like:

```js
grep | awk | sed
```

Then the operations seem more logical in structure.

Comment: Thanks mate, I was worried about that =) My current work around is to add this to the callback: 

    var newResult = [];

    result.forEach(function(item){
        newResult.push(item.body);
    });

Comment: @PaulParton It's just how it is, and makes sense really. Think "unix pipe" as per the edit. There are no "wildcard" operators here either. You get what you ask for.